# Decorator backoff.on_predicate not waiting as expected

Tags: python-3.x, exponential-backoff

I'm checking the constant interval between calls and found, that in this infinite loop, the time between consecutive calls is not 5 seconds and varies by random, though less than 5 sec. Don't understand, why.

```
from datetime import datetime
from backoff import on_predicate, constant

@on_predicate(constant, interval=5)
def fnc(i):
    print('%s %d' % (datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S:%f"),i), flush=True)
    return i

for i in range(7):
    fnc(i)
```

Output:

```
17:48:48:348775 0
17:48:50:898752 0
17:48:52:686353 0
17:48:53:037900 0
17:48:57:264762 0
17:48:58:348803 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `backoff` library uses a jitter function to randomize the interval.  It's normally what you want when doing exponential backoff or similar, but might be surprising when using the `constant` wait generator.  To disable jitter, specify `jitter=None`:

```
@on_predicate(constant, interval=5, jitter=None)
def fnc(i):
    print('%s %d' % (datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S:%f"),i), flush=True)
    return i
```